# how do i make "*" print vertically on python loops?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a horizonal and vertical list; made by inputs.
Horizontal list is done and looks like this:

```
0-29 : *
30-39 : **
40-69 : **
70-100 : **
```

However now I need to make the stars go from top to bottom like this:

```
1-10 10-20 20-30
 *     *     *
 *     *
 *
```

But all it comes up like is :

```
0-29  **30-39  *40-69  ***70-100
```

I've tried different coding and this the closest I've come up with. Any tips on how to make the stars go vertically?

```
var = ""
var= "0-29  "
for x in range(cat1):
        var += '*'
print(var, end="")

var = ""
var= "30-39  "
for x in range(cat2):
        var += '*'
print(var, end="")

var = ""
var= "40-69  "
for x in range(cat3):
        var += '*'
print(var, end="")

var = ""
var= "70-100  "
for x in range(cat4):
        var += '*'
print(var, end="")
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question itself. Your question should be a [mcve] which illustrates the problem.

Comment: please don't vandalize your post. it has some quite good answers, the question must remain readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) to structure the output positions for every line. I made some assumptions about your values for `cat`. Do see if the code snippet below makes sense to you.

```
cat1 = 2
cat2 = 3
cat3 = 1
cat4 = 4

header = ['0-29', '30-39', '40-69', '70-100']
print(' '.join(header))
for x in range(max(cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)):
    print(" {0}     {1}     {2}     {3}".format(
        '*' if x < cat1 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat2 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat3 else ' ',
        '*' if x < cat4 else ' '
    ))
```

The resultant output will be like this.

```
0-29 30-39 40-69 70-100
 *     *     *     *
 *     *           *
       *           *
                   *
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. I've tried manually adding toprint"" "*" but that's a very big mess. Thank you. A lot.

Answer (score 2):

you can't "print vertically". print is always in horizontal lines. You need to build your output line by line, or use a dedicated library like ncurses:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1):

```
def histogram (list):
    for x in range(len(list)):

        vertical = ''
        while( x > 0) :
            vertical += "_"
            x -= 1
        print(vertical)

histogram =([ 1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for providing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?